# mongodb npm preventing application to run on www, yet runs on localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, npm, cpanel

I have this node.js accounts app that I'm trying to implement a mongoDB database onto, but it seems to have errors when I upload it to cpanel. My mongoDB url is in this format: mongodb+srv://:@. After some experimenting, turning the Node.js version to ^14 caused errors to stop, but the app still wouldn't run (going to the url reslted in a 503 error, this is the current state of the server).

github: https://github.com/codingtuba/accounts.aimedtuba/tree/mongodb

before mongo DB: https://github.com/codingtuba/accounts.aimedtuba

Comment: Is your mongodb running locally in the server or is it cloud based?

Comment: I'm using mongoDb atlas.

Comment: @SoroushBgm (ping)

Comment: In the GitHub repo you've provided, I can't see any connection to mongodb. Where's that?

Comment: https://github.com/codingtuba/accounts.aimedtuba/blob/mongodb/index.js line 2 & 18 (https://github.com/codingtuba/accounts.aimedtuba/tree/mongodb < mongoDB branch) @SoroushBgm

Comment: I’m not sure what’s wrong in there. I myself use mongoose. I believe it’s a lot better. I’m using atlas in local and remote servers with no problem.

Comment: It turns out that the problem wasn’t with mongodb, but it was with require(“./apikeys”). CPanel is weird like that.